# Communicate between microservices on the same machine without exposing a public API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, microservices

I am relatively new to Camel and Spring, and I am making a service to predict stock prices using a neural network to practise using Camel, Spring and also DL4J.

My service is divided into 5 microservices (Gateway, H2 SQL Database, Admin Console, Data Fetcher, DL4J Handler) which will each run in their own Java application. Each one has a REST API.

How can I prevent an external computer from connecting to 4 of the services, while leaving the gateway open and connectable?

`To clarify:`

All 5 services have a REST endpoint, and they are all visible to each other because they are all running on the same machine and can connect with `localhost:port`. I'd like to know how I can *prevent an external computer* from connecting to 4 of the services, whilst leaving 1 (the gateway) still connectable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing unique about Spring or Camel here.

Each one has an REST API, meaning there's an HTTP endpoint, meaning each service has bound its server port on localhost, and so can reach each other via `http://localhost:<port>`, assuming nothing is running in a VM or Docker container

You should also be able to use the gateway on localhost

Comment: This is the strategy I have begun to implement, but it doesn't solve the issue: All 5 services have a REST endpoint (all of which are visible to one another), but only 1's REST endpoint should be visible to a computer connecting from across the internet. (I could likely achieve this through port forwarding, but I'd like to know whether there is an in-code equivalent) EDIT: I realised that you answered my exact question, but the question wasn't exactly what I wanted to ask - apologies! I have now edited!

Comment: If you don't want any services externally visible except for the gateway/proxy, then don't port forward them and explicitly disallow incoming firewall connections to them